# How to pass variable in data property of apexcharts

Tags: html, model-view-controller, apexcharts

I have passed the variable Apexcharts name Managerslt  which is type of array. But nothing is going to happen after running the code.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Favouritism',
    data: [managerslt]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `managerslt` is an array, you don't need to include it in another array.

```
var managerslt = [23, 34, 12, 54, 32]

series: [{
  name: 'Favouritism',
  data: managerslt
}]
```

Read more how to structure your data here - https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/